# scroll bar - browser scrolling up automatically when user selects or writing text in ckeditor using chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser, scroll, ckeditor

Scroll bar: browser scrolling up automatically when user selects or writing some text in CK Editor, using chrome.

I am using Full feature CK Editor as well, this issue not in Firefox or IE, but in chrome.

Please anyone have idea about this issue.

Comment: I've exactly the same issue, but in Safari. In Chrome it works well